# Show a linear map $\varphi: V \rightarrow V$ is a homomorphism if and only if $g \varphi= \varphi$ for all $ g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Can anyone help me to show the if and only if. I have tried to show it by assume the first part and show the second part and converse but I can't figure it out.

Lemma: 
Let $V$ be a representation of finite group $G$. Then the set of linear maps from $V$ to $V$ forms a vector space with pointwise addition and scalar multiplikation, and if we have for $g \in G$ and a linear map $\varphi: V \rightarrow V$ define the map $g \varphi $ by $(g \varphi )(v)=g(\varphi (g^{-1}v))$, then this defines a representation of $G$ on the set of linear maps $V \rightarrow V$.

Further, a linear map $\varphi: V \rightarrow V$ is a homomorphism if and only if $g \varphi= \varphi$ for all $ g \in G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, if $V$ and $W$ are $G$-modules and $\varphi\colon G\longrightarrow H$ is a map, then $\varphi$ is a $G$-module homomorphsm if$$(\forall g\in G)(\forall v\in V):\varphi(gv)=g\varphi(v).$$But this is equivalent to$$(\forall g\in G)(\forall v\in V):\varphi(v)=g\varphi\left(g^{-1}v\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! But what about the other way? If I assume that $g \varphi = \varphi$ how do I show that the map is a homomorphism?

Comment: Because the assertion $g\varphi=\varphi$ means$$(\forall g\in G)(\forall v\in V):\varphi(v)=g\varphi\left(g^{-1}v\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much :) I know im asking many questions, but can you help me understand why the map $g \varphi $ is a representation? I have tried  to understand why it is a representation by looking at the definition of a representation, but I don't get it. $G$ is a group. And a representation of $G$ is a vectorpsace $V$ together with a homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$. Is it because the map $\varphi$ is a homomorphism that $g\varphi$ is a representation?

Comment: The map$$\begin{array}{ccc}G\times V&\longrightarrow&V\\(g,\varphi)&\mapsto&g\varphi\end{array}$$is a representation if $G$ because$$(\forall g,h\in G)\bigl(\forall\varphi\in GL(V)\bigr):(gh)\varphi=g(h\varphi).$$